# Codeigniter get current location

Tags: php, codeigniter, location

I use codeigniter. I want to get the current location of the page without some segments.

Example:

> my current location: "localhost/ci/site/home/all/1"
>
> I want to get this: "localhost/ci/site/home/all"

I already tried: current_url() but it gives me:

> "localhost/ci/site/home/all/1"

Sorry for my terrible english :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo base_url().$this->uri->segment(1).$this->uri->segment(2);
```

1 segment for controller, 2 for method. base_url returns your site base url. Don't forget include URI helper.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$query = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] ? '?'.$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'] : '';
echo $this->config->site_url().$this->uri->uri_string(). $query;
```